# TYPO3 show nested elements inside container with b13/container extension

Tags: nested, containers, typo3

I use the b13/container [1] extension, and I want to see the nested elements inside the edit part of the container. At the moment, it is only possible to see the elements inside the page view, but I need them also inside the element itself.

Before I used Gridelements, and there the nested childs are visible.

It should be with: `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns" AND "$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['*CTYPE*']['showitem']`

Is there a way to fix it?

I integrated the following XML Code, which shows me the nested elements, but the palette field for `tx_container_parent` is not visible, if I create a new one inside a container:

```xml
<myElements type="array">
    <TCEforms type="array">
        <label>Nested elements</label>
        <config>
            <type>inline</type>
            <foreign_table>tt_content</foreign_table>
            <foreign_field>tx_container_parent</foreign_field>
            <foreign_sortby>sorting</foreign_sortby>
            <maxitems>20</maxitems>
            <inline>
                <inlineNewButtonStyle>display: inline-block;</inlineNewButtonStyle>
            </inline>
            <size>5</size>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</myElements>
```

- [1] https://github.com/b13/container

Answer (score 0):

For all those with the same problem.
There is an extension, which creates a solution.

Just look for "inline container" and you will find it.